# How to call upon a function that references objects in C#?

Tags: c#, function, syntax, picturebox

this is probably a really dumb question but i couldn't really find an answer anywhere

Basically I have a function:

```
public int cardCheck(ref PictureBox userCard1, ref PictureBox userCard2, ref PictureBox userCard3, ref PictureBox dealerCard1, ref PictureBox dealerCard2, ref PictureBox dealerCard3, int card, int cardNumber)
```

and I need to call upon that function. If I call that function like this:

```
uCard1 = cardCheck(card, cardNumber);
```

it tells me that I need references to those picture boxes. However, when I add them in like so:

```
uCard1 = cardCheck(PictureBox userCard1, PictureBox userCard2, PictureBox userCard3, PictureBox dealerCard1, PictureBox dealerCard2, PictureBox dealerCard3, card, cardNumber);
```

it tells me that PictureBox is a type, which can't be used in that context.

I'm sure I'm making a really dumb syntax mistake, but I'm not sure where.
How do you correctly call upon a function that references objects in your program?

Comment: `uCard1 = cardCheck(ref userCard1, ref userCard2, ref userCard3, ref dealerCard1, ref dealerCard2, ref dealerCard3, card, cardNumber);` - although I suspect you don't need `ref`'s in the function signature.

Comment: @Igor that didn't seem to work for me either :/ any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to add pictureboxes (6 of them it seems) to your form and pass the names of those pictureboxes in as arguments to the function, with them having the `ref` keyword in front of the variable name.

Comment: @AlkalineDreams - I don't know what "that didn't seem to work" means.

Answer (score 0):

Based just on your second line of code, what you're missing is something like this:

`uCard1 = cardCheck(ref card, ref cardNumber);`

In C# when the parameter is labeled `ref` in the declaration, you have to add `ref` at the call site, as well.  Similarly for `out`.

But specifically, based on the declaration for `cardCheck` that you showed us, you probably need all of the params:

`int uCard1 = cardCheck(ref userCard1, ref userCard2, ref userCard3, ref dealerCard1, ref dealerCard2, ref dealerCard3, card, cardNumber);`

`ref` means that you're passing in an object, and if the function you're calling modifies it then you will get back that modified version.

You must also have defined your own

```
PictureBox userCard1 = new PictureBox(blah blah);
PictureBox userCard2 = new PictureBox(blah blah);
PictureBox userCard3 = new PictureBox(blah blah);
PictureBox dealerCard1 = new PictureBox(blah blah);
PictureBox dealerCard2 = new PictureBox(blah blah);
PictureBox dealerCard3 = new PictureBox(blah blah);
int card = 0;
int cardNumber = 0;
```

Something like that...

Of course you can call your local variables whatever you want to.  And the function you're calling, `cardCheck` is what determines what will happen with all of those variables, and all of those values.  You have to make all of that make sense - we don't know the semantics of the code you're quoting to us.